# move items in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

How do I move items up and down from their position in linked list?

The text file contains data as follows which saved in the linked list. I want to sort the items according to the first items, i.e TY12354, ytpy217,TY12354dsaf....

> TY12354, Toyota, TY1257,2100000
>   SK2344, Skoda, SO2345, 180000
>   ytpy217,safsadf,asfasf,1241234
>   TY12354d,sfasdf,asfasf,235123412
>   TY12354dsaf,asdffasd,asfasfafsd,12344
>   ABC123,asdffasd,asfasfafsd,12344

I used the following code for sorting, but it doesn't work:

```
    for (int x = 0;x < (lstCar.size()-1); x++) {            
    c=(Car) lstCar.get(x);  //lstCar is the linked list
    d = (Car) lstCar.get(x+1);
    int compare =d.getRegNumber().compareTo(c.getRegNumber())  ;
    if(compare < 0){

        temp = d;
        lstCar(x)=c;  //tried this method but it doesnt work
        //lstCar.sort(); 
        c = temp;
    }                 
}
```

Comment: Make a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), then `Collections.sort(yourArrayList, new YourComparator())`;

Comment: `lstCar(x)=c;` looks like you wanted to treat the collection as an array. While this is not possible, it would additionally be wrong syntactically. Adressing array elements is done with square brackets ---> `lstCar[x]=c`. But nonetheless, a collection cannot be (directly) accessed like an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right way to set an element in a LinkedList:

```
  lstCar(x)=c;  //tried this method but it doesnt work
```

Instead use:

```
  lstCar.set(x,c);
```

If you want to sort your list by keeping this approach (i.e. by doing yourself as shown), then the method .set(index, element) will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Java already has a function for that:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29